# Show error if data cannot be inserted

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I need to handle an error when non-unique data is inserted into the database. I have this code:

```
try {
   handler.addBookmark(new BookmarkModel(idBrand, brand, desc, types, detail, image));
   Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}catch (SQLiteException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I insert like this:

```
public long addBookmark(BookmarkModel bookmark) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, bookmark._id); // Must Unique
    values.put(KEY_BRAND, bookmark.brandName);
    values.put(KEY_DESC, bookmark.descTerm);
    values.put(KEY_TYPE, bookmark.type);
    values.put(KEY_DETAIL, bookmark.detail);
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, bookmark.image);
    return db.insert(TABLE_BOOKMARK, null, values);
    //db.close();
}
```

Logcat of the error that occurs:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column id is not unique (code 19)
```

The data was not inserted, but I was unable to show the error message. How can I show the toast to let the user know the insert failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the [`insertOrThrow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method which will throw an SQLiteConstraintException if this occurs.

Then, you can put your insert into a try/catch block:

```
try{
   db.insertOrThrow(table, columnHack, values);
} catch (SQLiteConstraintException e){
   Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to insert values.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not set `_id` yourself. This line should be gone:

```
values.put(KEY_ID, bookmark._id); // Must Unique
```

If your table schema sets it up correctly (`_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`) then this is auto incremented long value. Nothing you should touch on insert.

Comment: i want to add a data that have unique id, and i want to handle an error message when it fail

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. just set an id to PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT and set 1 text UNIQUE . for methode that handle an error, i use insertOrThrow and use it with try-catch .